# How can I add indexes to array instead of having keys start at zero?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array but the key/indexing showing only zero for all the values instead of **0,1,2,3,4,5**. When I print the array, it shows as

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://giphy.com/ladygaga
)
Array
(
    [0] => https://plus.google.com/+LadyGaga
)
Array
(
    [0] => https://twitter.com/ladygaga
)
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.facebook.com/ladygaga
)
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.instagram.com/ladygaga/
)
```

Here's my code

```
foreach($social_media as $social){

    $typesocial = $social['type'];
    $val = array($social['url']['resource']);

    if ($social['type'] === 'social network') 
    {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($val); echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I see here 5 array's al containiing one value and all keys are 0.

Comment: Maybe just `$val = $social['url']['resource'];`?

Comment: $social['url']['resource'] contains an array and $social_media contains five items with the $social['url']['resource'] in it.

Comment: @IvoP exactly, but the question is how can we add indexing to it instead of 0?

Comment: @Waleedviews - I changed your question so it's more relevant to your actual question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
 foreach($social_media as $social){

    $typesocial = $social['type'];
    if($social['type'] === 'social network') {
      $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
      $key = preg_match('#([a-z]*)\.[a-z]+$#', $host, $a);
      $valKey[$key] = $social['url']['resource'];
      $val[] = $social['url']['resource'];
    }

}
print_r($val);
print_r($valKey);
```

Comment: It prints all the values instead of 
if ($social['type'] === 'social network') {
                       echo '<pre>'; print_r($val); echo '</pre>';         
                                
                            }

Comment: I edited to only add a value to the array when equal to that string. It will always number like 0, 1,2, 3 regardless of the number of skipped entries

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, one more thing is it possible to have Value name as a key? For example if array value has facebook link, the key should be facebook instead of 0,1,2

Comment: that would be possible IF you can read that key from the url. I will make an edit of the answer

Comment: answer is now edited. I did no checks on "is key already present". and it would fail on facebook.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

You have always assign value in array array($social['url']['resource']); so one value show on index 0 always remove this array try the following code

```
 $val = array();
foreach($social_media as $social){

    $typesocial = $social['type'];
    $val[] = (isset($social['url']['resource'])) ? $social['url']['resource'] : '';

    if ($social['type'] === 'social network') 
    {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($val); echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Comment: It only prints values not indexing.